# Creating a new dataframe from the output of .value_counts() on an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was just wondering is it possible to get the output of a pandas .value_counts() to be a new dataframe? It is typically output in a couple of columns looking like a table, but something like the following doesn't work:

```
new_df = df['col'].value_counts()
```

And a related question (which is in part why I want to do the above) is I am struggling with using the output of `df['col'].value_counts()`. 
If your data looks like this:

```
Num, Let
0,A
1,A
2,B
```

Then you can run

```
counts = df['Let'].value_counts()
print counts['A']
```

which prints 2. And I could assign this value of 2 to a variable, e.g. `max_let=counts['A']`. If I wanted to output the max I could also do something like `counts.head(1)` I believe. But what if I wanted to assign the string 'A' to a variable aswell (that is why I wanted the extra dataframe), is that possible? And is there a way to set `max_let` to take the value of whatever comes out without having to specify 'A' (as I can't seem to do it using `counts.head(1)`?

Hopefully that wasn't too convoluted.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using `reset_index`

```
new_df = df['col'].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Comment: Expected output is something like:
`A   2
B   1`
I can set the new_df equal to this and print new_df, but whereas on a normal dataframe you can perfore things like print df.iat[0,0] to look at an element, I can't do that with my new_df (and it's being able to pull out the elements that I want to do). Just had a go with your `reset_index()` and still getting an error: `'function' object has no attribute 'iat'` when I try `new_df.iat[0,0]`

  (sorry I hit enter before I'd fully typed a response)

Comment: @Ben try reset_index as I listed

Comment: Oh wait, my mistake - that has worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ben if this work would you like accept it ? check mark at the left